# How to make a div element to auto fit when the other one has a fixed width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have total brain freeze and I would appreciate a helping hand how to fix it.

I have 2x div elements. Called left and right:

```
.left {width:50%;float:left;}
.right {width:50%;float:left;}
```

What I am trying to do is to make the right one fixed with a width of 320px and the left one with auto if the browser is shrinked.

```
.left {width:auto}
.right {width:320px}
```

But I can't figure it out how to make it work, since the right element jumps straight under the left one and gets width 100%.

I want it to behaive like this:

[------- LEFT-------][--- RIGHT---]

When I shrink the brwoser window:

[--- LEFT---][--- RIGHT---]

Thanks in advance, Jack

Comment: I'd use css calc() rather then javascript (depending on what browsers you need to support)

Comment: "What I am trying to do is to make the left one fixed with a width of 320px and the right one with auto if the browser is shrinked." Your wrote the opposite of what you wanted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you. You were on the right track

```
.left {width:320px; height:20px; background-color:red; float:left}
.right {width:auto; height:20px; background-color:blue; float:left, margin-left:320px}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/R5zCV/1/)

Comment: as I said, it works great, but it's the right one I want fixed, trying to turn the vaules around, but it's messy, able to give me a hint again ;)?

Comment: @user3244239 just change the `.right` to `.left` and vice versa.

Comment: answer updated now. You just needed to flip it and add some display:inline as well as reversing the margin so it pushes off the right

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
}
#right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:320px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#left").width($(window).innerWidth()-$("#right").outerWidth());
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wPDCN/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just add `float:right;` to your `.right` div.

```
<div style="width: 320px; float:right">foo</div>
<div style="width: auto">bar</div>
```

(The `width: auto` isn't strictly necessary, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent feature in css which allows you to do that, it is called **flexbox**:

```
  display: flex;
```

Before flexbox there was no way to accomplish this without JS.

Check http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
and http://html5please.com/#flexbox

And a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/jakub_g/s5jAB/

Answer (score 1):

You may use this **pure n simple css, no JS and legacy browser compatible** solution

Advantages: **Your right Div grows with the left**

**html**:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left"> </div>
    <div class="right"> </div>
</div>
```

**css**: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceX52/)

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
}
.left{
  margin-right: 320px;
  background: grey;
}
.right{
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: yellow;
}
```